# VSCode - How do I change the color of constants only in a javascript file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

With the recent update to vscode, I can not for the life of me find the setting to revert this back to the old color. Seems like it's all constants that were changed to this green color, while regular variables stayed the same. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Disable the `Semantic Highlighting` setting.

Comment: Where is that? The only thing I found in the theme settings were:    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false,
    "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
        "enabled": false, // enable semantic highlighting for all themes
        "rules": {
            "*.declaration": { "foreground": "#9cdcfe" }
        }
    }

Neither fixes the issue

Comment: nevermind found it I think

Answer (score 9):

Not sure how to do it only for .js files, but this setting changes only constants and not all declarations. Paste this inside your VsCode `settings.json`

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
          {
            "scope": "variable.other.constant",
            "settings": {
              "foreground": "#f5f5f5"
            }
          }
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 4):

Added this to settings.json for the theme:

```
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "enabled": true, // enable semantic highlighting for all themes
    "rules": {
        "*.readonly": { "foreground": "#9cdcfe" },
        "*.declaration": { "foreground": "#9cdcfe" }
    }
}
```

Comment: This also changes the color of the function declarations. got me exited for 2 seconds.